# undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string'

Tags: matlab, linker, protocol-buffers, caffe, mex

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. And I am trying to use `mex` command from MATLAB, which links caffe library and protobuf. However, the problem happens when I run this script:

```
mex imageset_to_leveldb.cpp -lcaffe -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lleveldb -llmdb ...
 -L/home/wei/Caffe/build/lib ...
 -I/home/wei/Caffe/build/src/caffe/proto

mex serialized_pairs_to_leveldb.cpp -lcaffe -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lleveldb -llmdb ...
 -L/home/wei/Caffe/build/lib ...
 -I/home/wei/Caffe/build/src/caffe/proto
```

It returns the error:

```
Building with 'g++'.
Warning: You are using gcc version '4.8.4'. The version of gcc is not supported. The
version currently supported with MEX is '4.7.x'. For a list of currently supported
compilers see: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release.
> In compile (line 2)
Error using mex
/tmp/mex_3078197848859966_35312/imageset_to_leveldb.o: In function `process(unsigned
char*, int, int, int, char const*)':
imageset_to_leveldb.cpp:(.text+0x5dd): undefined reference to
`google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems cannot find protobuf lib file. So I check the protobuf version and path as:

```
>>> import google.protobuf
>>> print google.protobuf.__version__
3.1.0.post1
>>> google.protobuf
<module 'google.protobuf' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/__init__.pyc'>
```

I use Anaconda. However, the version check above is from outside of Anaconda Python. In conda environment, I do not have protobuf.

I compiled caffe inside of conda environment, which passes all the test with no error.

I google it, which suggests to `conda install protobuf`. It does not seem working for me.

Any idea on this?

Comment: As suggested in the warning, try roll back to 4.7. And make sure no conflict of using gcc and g++ using `ln -s` to specify the exact version.